# using super() method within the parent class

Tags: oop, inheritance, superclass

I am a bit confused. I was reading a book about Django, and I came across a parent class that is calling itself using `super()` method. I am used to subclasses calling parent class using `super()`, but not a parent class calling itself, especially using super method. see the code below:

```
    class OwnerMixin(object):
        def get_queryset(self):
            qs = super(OwnerMixin, self).get_queryset()
            return qs.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

Comment: It's not calling itself, but it is incorrectly assuming that some ancestor class in its MRO has a `get_queryset` method.

Comment: It's possible that it is designed under the *assumption* that it will only be used in a class hierarchy where something does supply `get_queryset()`, though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [use of python super function in django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141820/use-of-python-super-function-in-django-model)